# When desktop icon is deleted so is the .desktop file

Tags: .desktop, ubuntu-mate

I made this desktop file so I could add an appimage to my menu.

I have it as a panel item, so I do not need a desktop icon.

But if I delete the icon, the desktop file is deleted as well.

How can I fix that?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Avidemux
Exec=/home/andy/AppImage_Programs/avidemux_2.8.1_legacy.appImage
Icon=/home/andy/ICONS/avidemux.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

[image]

Comment: The .desktop file is in /home/andy/Desktop/. @Nmath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a manner of speaking, the "icon" you see *is* the `.desktop` file. (This isn't literally true, but it works that way.)

Don't delete it. Move it to `~/.local/share/applications`.

Also, your icons "belong" in `~/.local/share/icons`. You don't need `~/ICONS`. Your `.desktop` files will find them without the full path.